# In Ember 1.x, how do I use a modal in willTransition()

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to open a modal dialog when someone tries to navigate away from a page with a form that isn't complete. I have the modal template built, but I can't figure out how to implement it. Here's what I have:

```
actions: {
    willTransition: function( transition ){
        var model = this.currentModel;

        if( model.get( 'isDirty' ) ){
            this.render( 'my-modal', {
                into: 'application',
                outlet: 'modal'
        } );
            if(!this.get(abortConfirmed) {
                transition.abort();
            } else {
               model.rollback();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: The dirty checking works and I can generate a prompt, but this modal thing is not working

Comment: What does the console say? Did u add the {{outlet "modal"}} into the application template?

Comment: @ahmed.hoban: No errors in the console, and also no indication of even trying to render the modal. `{{outlet "modal"}}` is in _application.hbs_

Comment: `transition.abort();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the workflow I use.

1). in the `willTransition(transition)` hook, do the check to see if you should show the modal.

2). If you should show the modal (in your case, when the model `isDirty`), call `transition.abort()`. You must do this to prevent the transition from happening. You also though need a second property on your controller that determines whether or not the transition has been authorized. So really, you check `model.get('isDirty) && this.controller.get('transitionAuthorized')`

3). You need a way to pass state to your modal or for your modal to be able to communicate back with the page that has created the modal. I personally pass a `continueFn` and a `cancelFn` to my modals that close over the current context. Something like

```
var continueFn = this.createUnsavedDialogContinueFn(this, transition);
```

where that function is:

```
createUnsavedDialogContinueFn: function(context, transition){
        return function(){
            context.controller.set('transitionAuthorized', true);
            transition.retry();
        }
}
```

I pass this `continueFn` to the modal, whose `I don't care if I have Pending changes` button calls via an action. You can, though, delegate this work back to the controller/route if that feels easier for you. What's important is that you set the `transitionAuthorized` to `true` and call `transition.retry()`

4). calling `transition.retry` will pass back thru the `willTransition` but this time you have set `transitionAuthorized` to true and everything passes through.

Comment: Thanks @sunrize920, I'll try that out. I'll upvote as soon as I'm able.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the transition from occurring.  Add transition.abort() at the bottom of your 'isDirty' check.

Comment: The question is about how to generate a modal, not aborting the transition. The modal will have the text "You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to leave this page?" with the options "yes" or "cancel". If the user clicks cancel, `transition.abort()` will be called. If the user clicks "yes" `model.rollback()` will be called and the transition will complete. I have temporarily solved it by doing a `confirm('Are you sure...?'); if (!confirm) {transition.abort()}`, but it's not what I'd call pleasing to the eye.

Comment: You still need to abort the initial transition.  I have basically the same code you're expressing in my app.  Have your modal call an action 'confirmTransition' and then use something like:  `if (model.get('isDirty') && !this.get('abortConfirmed'))`

Comment: https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/

Comment: @ScottNedderman: I've updated the code for how I think it _should_ look. from what you're telling me: I should call `transition.abort()` before I even render the modal, which to me (and my admittedly novice understanding of Ember) defeats the purpose of rendering a modal in the first place. You say `transition.abort()` before `this.render('my-modal')`, where I say `this.render('my-modal')` then `transition.abort()` when `cancel` button on the modal has been clicked. Where am I getting confused?